# PHP's SimpleXML: How to use colons in names

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I am trying to generate an RSS Google Merchant, using SimpleXML.

The sample given by Google is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" 
xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
<title>The name of your data feed</title>
<link>http://www.example.com</link>
<description>A description of your content</description>
<item>
<title>Red wool sweater</title>
<link> http://www.example.com/item1-info-page.html</link>
<description>Comfortable and soft, this sweater will keep you warm on those cold winter nights.</description>
<g:image_link>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</g:image_link> <g:price>25</g:price> <g:condition>new</g:condition> <g:id>1a</g:id>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

My code has things like:

```
$product->addChild("g:condition", 'new');
```

Which generates:

```
<condition>new</condition>
```

I read online that I should instead use:

```
$product->addChild("g:condition", 'new', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
```

Which now generates:

```
<g:condition xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">new</g:condition>
```

This seems very counter-intuitive to me, as now the "xmlns" declaration is on almost EVERY line of my RSS feed intead of just once in the root element.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 16):

As @ceejayoz said, you need to add the "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" namespace to the root node so that SimpleXML knows the namespace has already been declared and doesn't emit a duplicate prefix binding.

I think you may need to read a [tutorial on XML Namespaces](http://zvon.org/comp/m/namespace.html), because I'm not sure you really understand what the "g:" is doing here.

Here is a more complete example.
XML:

```
$xml = <<<EOT 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"> 
  <channel> 
    <title>The name of your data feed</title> 
    <link>http://www.example.com</link> 
    <description>A description of your content</description> 
    <item> 
      <title>Red wool sweater</title> 
      <link> http://www.example.com/item1-info-page.html</link> 
      <description>Comfortable and soft, this sweater will keep you warm on those cold winter nights.</description> 
      <g:image_link>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</g:image_link> 
      <g:price>25</g:price> 
      <g:id>1a</g:id> 
    </item> 
  </channel> 
</rss> 
EOT 
;
```

Code:

```
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); 
$NS = array( 
    'g' => 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' 
); 
$rss->registerXPathNamespace('g', $NS['g']); 
$product = $rss->channel->item[0]; // example 

// Use the complete namespace. 
// Don't add "g" prefix to element name--what prefix will be used is 
// something SimpleXML takes care of. 
$product->addChild('condition', 'new', $NS['g']); 

echo $rss->asXML();
```

I usually use this pattern to deal with namespaces easily:

```
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); 
$NS = array( 
    'g' => 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' 
    // whatever other namespaces you want 
); 
// now register them all in the root 
foreach ($NS as $prefix => $name) { 
    $rss->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $name); 
} 
// Then turn $NS to an object for more convenient syntax 
$NS = (object) $NS; 
// If I need the namespace name later, I access like so: 
$element->addChild('localName', 'Value', $NS->g);
```

Comment: Where you have `new SimpleXMLElement($xml)`, you don't show what $xml is. This is what I ended up using (wasn't working without it): `'<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"></rss>'`

Comment: Read more carefully: the first code block in the answer starts with `$xml = ` and evaluates to an xml string.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks for the detailled solution !

Comment: I think there's a bit of a misunderstand here. As its name suggests, `registerXPathNamespace` is only used when querying with XPath, and has nothing to do with adding namespaces to a document you're generating.

Answer (score 15):

This do the trick:

```
$product->addChild('xmlns:g:condition', 'new');
```

Comment: This worked for me, and I feel actually answers the question - the other posts about namespaces and parents nodes having them were great, but my file already had the parent namespace and I just needed to add the "xmlns:" to get it to add the node correctly. Thanks!

Comment: This relies on a quirk (bug) in the XML library which doesn't notice that you've used illegal syntax for the tag name. It's not actually handling the namespace correctly in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that namespace to a parent node, preferably the root `rss` one, so that the child nodes can inherit it instead of having to explicitly specify it each time.

Comment: I tried

`$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss></rss>');
$xml->addAttribute('version','2.0');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');`

And then later:

`$product->addChild("g:condition", 'new');`

It generates:

`<condition>new</condition>`

It skips "g:" again ...

Comment: You need to still specify the namespace in the `addChild` calls. It just shouldn't be output because the root node already has it.