# Extra data in simplexml using namespaces

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to learn XML in php but there is something I dont understand when using namespaces.

This is my code

```
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement("<rss xmlns:g=\"http://base.google.com/ns/1.0\" version=\"2.0\"></rss>");

$make = $xml_data->addChild('channel');

$make->addChild('g:model', 'foo', 'g');
$make->addChild('g:model', 'bar', 'g');
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
print_r($xml_data->asXML());
```

When looking at guides on the internet I expect to get this.

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<g:model>foo</model>
<g:model>bar</g:model>
</channel>
</rss>
```

But I get this

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<g:model xmlns:g="g">foo</model>
<g:model xmlns:g="g">bar</g:model>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Why do I get this extra xmlnsg:="g" and what does it do? Looking at other feeds, they dont seem to get this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must omit the `xmlns` alias when adding the child, and provide the full `xmlns` in the 3rd parameter (not the alias):

```
$make->addChild('model', 'foo', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
```

You can use a technique [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287355/314291) to simplify / DRY up management of the namespaces

Re: What does `<g:model xmlns:g="g">foo</model>` do?
This overrides the previous definition of the `g` alias (and corrupts it in your case to `g`)