# How to add namespace with SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I will have to produce this XML using simpleXML in php:

```
<fr:program name="fundref">
  <fr:assertion name="funder_name">ABC Inc.
    <fr:assertion name="funder_identifier">http://dx.doi.org/10.13039/xxxxxxxxxx</fr:assertion>
  </fr:assertion>    
  <fr:assertion name="award_number">BXDFSDS</fr:assertion>
</fr:program>
```

I tried:

```
$fundRef = $myXML->addChild('fr', '', 'program');
```

But this is creating:

```
<fr xmlns="program" name="fundref">
```

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, `<fr>` is the tag and `:program` is the namespace.

Comment: Oups, sory. Will edit my answer - aswerd edited.

Comment: I did a little of research and the few minutes I spent looking for it shows that it's going to be hard. Did you tried `$fundRef = $myXML->addChild('fr:program', '');`? (probably won't work)

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, your example is not working. Why posting this comment if you think that it will be hard and not work ;)

Comment: Well, better than being shut. At least I'm trying to provide some help or at least a path to follow. By the way, you have a spelling mistake on your first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine namespace like this

$myXML->addChild('fr:program', '', 'http://ololo.com/ns/1.0');

This should help [PHP's SimpleXML: How to use colons in names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018808/phps-simplexml-how-to-use-colons-in-names#3018808)